# How to find what channel the SSID is on?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ssid

I'd like to see what channel (e.g. 1-10, I believe) each SSID in the list is. How can I find that information?

Comment: `cmd /k netsh wlan show all`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install inSSIDer from [MetaGeek](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/). It is simple to use and gives you information on your and other SSIDs in your area.

[image: inSSIDer screenshot]

Comment: inSSIDer is awesome, but I think for more users, something built into the operating system would be better.

Comment: @Moab, @Joel Coehoorn  What is considered good RSSI?  There are a ton of SSIDs in the building I am in and I am trying to a find a spare channel.  I currently get RSSI of -18 to -20.  Is this good?

Comment: @AngyHacker I'm getting 4 out of 5 bars on the Win7 indicator for -60. If you look at the "time graph" window it is colour coded. -20 is well into the green! RSSI is in negative dB's so the lower the number the better the signal.

Comment: Sadly this program is not free.

Comment: It used to be free. However, it is indeed no longer available for free directly from MetaGeek. Freeware archives may still have it, though. Like CHIP, a German computer magazine: http://www.chip.de/downloads/inSSIDer-Home-letzte-Freeware-Version_41273737.html

Answer (score 24):

On a Command Prompt, type:

```
netsh wlan show all
```

Comment: The more pipe will be useful: `netsh wlan show all | more`

Answer (score 14):

Menu start run cmd.exe and type:

```
netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid
```

Comment: The output of this command is much simpler than others.

Answer (score 9):

From a cmd (command) prompt, type:

```
netsh wlan show interfaces
```

Comment: This is the reply that best answered my question: how to know the channel of the Wi-Fi network I'm already connected to.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [Free NetSpot](https://www.netspotapp.com/) for these purposes. All the necessary information is in the Discover mode window. Here are some screenshots:

[image: Discover mode - NetSpot]

[image: Channel interference - NetSpot]

Answer (score 0):

Use either of these

```
netsh wlan show interface name="Wi-Fi" | findstr "Channel"
netsh wlan show networks interface="Wi-Fi" mode=bssid | findstr "Channel"
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [Acrylic Wifi](https://www.acrylicwifi.com/en/wlan-software/wlan-scanner-acrylic-wifi-free/). The Home version is for free.
It runs on Windows 7,8,10 but requires .NET Framework 4.5

[image]